# Best way to create SpriteBatch when wrapping underlying objects

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xna, wrapper, factory-pattern

The problem itself is quite simple here, but all solutions seem to be a bad bunch, so I cannot decide on which is best, so thought I should ask in here...

I currently wrap a few of the XNA components (SpriteBatch, GraphicsDevice, ContentLoader etc), for the most part they wrap everything 1-1 but there are a few differences where optional arguments cut down on function overloading. This is mainly done to enable Dependency Injection  and to enable me to mock a lot easier in tests, as I would rather go with an injection pattern rather than a service locator pattern (although I have also made a NinjectServiceProvider which implements IServiceProvider).

Anyway the main problem here is that I need to new up a few different ISpriteBatch objects due to different components using different blend modes etc. So I have made a SpriteBatchFactory object to new on up. Before I continue here are some example snippets so you can see where I am coming from:

```
public class MySpriteBatch : ISpriteBatch
{
    private SpriteBatch underlyingSpriteBatch;
    private IGraphicsDevice graphicsDevice;

    public MySpriteBatch(SpriteBatch underlyingSpriteBatch, 
        IGraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    { 
        this.underlyingSpriteBatch = underlyingSpriteBatch; 
        this.graphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
    }

// ...
}
```

MyGraphicsDevice:

```
public class MyGraphicsDevice : IGraphicsDevice
{
    private GraphicsDevice underlyingGraphicsDevice;

    public MyGraphicsDevice(GraphicsDevice underlyingDevice)
    {
        this.underlyingGraphicsDevice = underlyingDevice;
    }

    // ...
}
```

SpriteBatchFactory:

```
public class SpriteBatchFactory
{
    public SpriteBatchFactory(IGraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        this.GraphicsDevice = graphicsDevice;
    }

    public IGraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice { get; private set; }

    public ISpriteBatch Create()
    {
        var underlyingGraphicsDevice = ????

        var underlyingSpriteBatch =
            new SpriteBatch(underlyingGraphicsDevice);

        return new MySpriteBatch(underlyingSpriteBatch,
            this.GraphicsDevice);
    }
}
```

Now as you can see to new up a MySpriteBatch (ISpriteBatch), I require a new SpriteBatch, which in turn requires a GraphicsDevice instance... which is where I am unsure as to how best satisfy this dependency... A few solutions I have thought of are:

1) MyGraphicsDevice contains this, but it is not exposed so I could expose it as an object at interface level or an actual GraphicsDevice at concrete class level. Either way this will require casting be it the object -> GraphicsDevice or IGraphicsDevice -> MyGraphicsDevice.

2) I give the SpriteBatchFactory a GraphicsDevice rather than IGraphicsDevice and new one up each time I need to new up the MySpriteBatch.

3) I make MySpriteBatch new up a SpriteBatch internally, and make it require a MyGraphicsDevice and expose it there, so the MySpriteBatch has no external dependency on SpriteBatch.

I think the 3rd one is sounding the more encapsulated way of doing this but I dont really like either way, so can anyone else think of a nicer way to solve this? I am not that bothered about having XNA dependencies as I am not trying to make this cross platform, just trying to give me a more controllable layer between Xna and my framework.

=== Edit ===

When I say I am wrapping the underlying components I mean literally wrapping the calls, i.e:

```
public class MyGraphicsDevice : IGraphicsDevice
{
    private GraphicsDevice underlyingGraphicsDevice;

    public MyGraphicsDevice(GraphicsDevice underlyingDevice)
    {
        this.underlyingGraphicsDevice = underlyingDevice;
    }

    public VertexBuffer[] GetVertexBuffers()
    {
        return underlyingGraphicsDevice.GetVertexBuffers();
    }

    public void SetRenderTarget(RenderTarget2D renderTarget)
    {
        underlyingGraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
    }

    // ...
}
```

So there is no custom logic really, its just a dumb wrapper.

Comment: (You should mention which DI framework you are using). Maybe you shouldn't be needing to ask these questions; firstly, XNA wasn't written with unit testing in mind - making it difficult to fit it into an existing DI framework. Secondly I would worry about the performance (unless you are using some fast like Ninject). There is a good chance that existing DI frameworks just won't work - you may have to design your own. That, or, implement a further layer on top of XNA which further abstracts XNA's concepts (which you can then make DI-aware).

Comment: Didn't want to make the question any more complex than is needed, I am using Ninject but this question is not concerned about that. The performance impact is so small its not even worth worrying about, fast is fast enough. I know XNA was not designed with this in mind, but there is no reason (like you say) why I cannot just write a control layer (which is what I have done) that sits on top of XNA, so as far as any of my framework is concerned it only uses these interfaces. The problem as the question indicates is how best to deal with the underlying types when they are required by the wrappers

Comment: That's the thing, there is a good chance you will need to wrap or abstract those underlying objects as well. For example: instead of requiring a `GraphicsDevice` on all your objects; possibly abstract it so far away that your merely need one on your game-concrete `IMeshGeometry`; your unit test one wouldn't ever touch the `GraphicsDevice`. A good starting point for some existing code that should be somewhat DI-ready would be Axiom3D (as they are cross-platform and therefore DI is a top priority).

Comment: That's what I have done... Everything throughout *my* framework uses ISpriteBatch, IGraphicsDevice etc, each of which has a matching implementation which wraps the underlying xna instances. However when you need to create a new object, such as ISpriteBatch you need a new underlying xna object, as thats what all the calls will delegate to. That bit there is the crux of the problem, as you cannot just will an underlying object into existance, it has to be created for you hidden from the  caller but SOMEWHERE that logic has to exist, in my case that logic is within the SpriteBatchFactory.

Comment: I see your problem more clearly now. Doesn't Ninject handle the case where concrete implementations has dependencies? You could just mark the `GraphicsDevice` as a concrete dependency on `XnaSpriteBatch` and hook them up into the kernel at game start.

Comment: At any rate I strongly recommend you look at Axiom3D. I don't think they unit test, but it **should** give you an idea of how to approach of how to make a game framework that **should** me DI-ready.

Comment: Just realised the typo in my main post XnaSpriteBatch should have been MySpriteBatch. Anyway the MySpriteBatch exposes an IGraphicsDevice (just like how SpriteBatch exposes GraphicsDevice). However the SpriteBatch requires the GraphicsDevice, but all I have available at that point is an IGraphicsDevice, which is where the problem stems from. As its either a case of expose it from the existing IGraphicsDevice somehow, or inject in the underlying xna GraphicsDevice and use that, but that also feels a bit hacky.

Comment: I have taken a quick look at Axiom but for the most part they have re-written large chunks of xna areas to make it fit with their framework. It is good to see how they have solved certain problems but I am merely wrapping calls, I am not trying to fully abstract in this instance, the less work I can get away with to provide an interfaced layer the better :)

Comment: **Your** `XnaSpriteBatch` (I don't think you will avoid writing it) should take a `GraphicsDevice` as a dependency (constructor params most likely), when it constructed take the `GraphicsDevice` you get in and create the `SpriteBatch`. Your `XnaSpriteBatch` should wrap (not implement) `SpriteBatch` - so you would simply marshal all the calls to a private member. I don't think you won't get away from **core** dependencies in any framework; you are going to have to work around the nature of XNA which will ultimately land up feeling hacky (`#region DRAGONS BE HERE!!!`).

Comment: This is where my 3rd option was heading, so it would new up a SpriteBatch internally rather than accept one through the constructor. Will edit the original post just to show an example of how I am wrapping, as I am doing what you say. Will leave the question open incase someone else comes out with a nicer solution.

Comment: You should potentially answer your own question in that case, but leave it 'unticked' for a day or two in case someone has a better answer.